# wpa_supplicant on Debian doesn't connect to network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, wifi-configuration, wpa2-psk

I'm currently trying to connect to my home WiFi network (WPA2 security), but when I run `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`, running `/sbin/iw wlan0 link` immediately after always returns `Not Connected`. `sudo dhclient -v wlan0` returns `No DHCPOFFERS Received`.

Running `sudo iwconfig wlan0 scan` shows that the network I'm trying to access is indeed in range and accessible, so the problem must be local.

I've checked `wpa_supplicant.conf` and the psk and ssid are definitely correct. The full contents are:

```
ap_scan=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
    ssid="<SSID>"
    scan_ssid=0
    proto=WPA
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    #psk="<pw>"
    psk=<converted psk from wpa_passphrase>
    pairwise=TKIP
    group=TKIP
}
```

The contents of my /etc/network/interfaces file are:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-ssid <SSID>
wpa_psk <PW>

wpa-ap-scan 1
pre-up sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -Dwext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
pre-up sleep 5
post-down sudo killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

EDIT:

I changed the contents of /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf to hold

```
pairwise=AES
pairwise=AES
```

but that got me an `invalid cipher` error, so I set both to `AES-CCMP`, which got me...the same error. I ended up just commenting those lines out. I ran `wpa_supplicant` again, but I still get `Not Connected` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Original WPA used TKIP.

WPA2 uses AES-CCMP.

If your network uses WPA2, you should be specifying AES, not TKIP.

Comment: I changed this, but got an error instead. See most recent edit to OP.

Comment: @GordonEstes I'm a Wi-Fi guy, but not a wpa_supplicant user. I didn't mean for you to literally type the string "AES" unless that was correct for the wpa_supplicant.conf file syntax. After your update I looked at the wpa_supplicant.conf man page for you, and it looks like you want the string "CCMP". If your AP is set to do WPA2 only (AES-CCMP only), then set CCMP as both your pairwise and group cipher.